# Rest API: return CompletableFuture in Controller does not make API run asyc

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, asynchronous

```
/**
 * Async work.
 */
@GetMapping(value = "/async/data/v4")
public void getDataAsyncV4() {
    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000); // Sleep for 1 second (does not block the main thread)
            return Data.builder().data("Some Data").threadId(Thread.currentThread().getId()).requestCameTime(System.currentTimeMillis()).build();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Async doesn't work if return CompletableFuture.
 */
@GetMapping(value = "/async/data/v5")
public CompletableFuture<Data> getDataAsyncV5() {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000); // block main thread
            return Data.builder().data("Some Data").threadId(Thread.currentThread().getId()).requestCameTime(System.currentTimeMillis()).build();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    });
}
```

I have two APIs as above and the problem is the only API method `getDataAsyncV4()` which returns void is run `asynchronously`, and the API method `getDataAsyncV5()` which returns `CompletableFuture` always blocks the main thread. I have tried different ways like using annotation `@EnableAsync`,  adding customer Executor.. but it doesn't work, I still can't understand why.

Comment: you need to both place `@EnableAsync` somewhere in configuration and mark asynchronous controller method  (or class) as `@Async`

Answer (score 1):

/v4 and /v5 are executing asynchronously.

In fact, `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync()` works as intended. If you don't provide any executor to `supplyAsync()`, it will default to using the ForkJoinPool. You can observe this by logging the thread name like this:

```java
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("async time: " + System.currentTimeMillis() + ", threadName: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return Data.builder().data("Some Data").threadId(Thread.currentThread().getId()).requestCameTime(System.currentTimeMillis()).build();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
});
```

If you make multiple requests simultaneously, you will see output similar to the following:

```
async time: 1694959567112, threadName: ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1
async time: 1694959567112, threadName: ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2
async time: 1694959567115, threadName: ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3
```

For each parallel execution, the ForkJoinPool assigns a different thread (worker) from its pool.

The only difference between v4 and v5 is that v4 does not return the result and, therefore, does not wait for the completion of `Thread.sleep(1000);` in the current 'main' (http-nio) thread. Instead, it immediately releases the current thread and returns the response '200 OK'.

Lastly, if you're concerned about not holding threads in controllers and ensuring your APIs are always available, Spring Boot handles it automatically. By default, Spring Boot uses the Tomcat web server and creates an executor with 200 threads in the pool.

Answer (score 0):

To make an API asynchronous, you need to annotate your application class (the class with `@SpringBootApplication`) with `@EnableAsync` annotation. Then annotate the method you want to run asynchronously with `@Async` and change the return type of the method to `CompletableFuture<YourType>`.
The return statement of the method would be something like this:

```
return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(yourType);
```

This is a complete example:

```
@Async
public CompletableFuture<User> findUser(String user) throws InterruptedException {
  User results = //...
  return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(results);
}
```

For more details see the official docs: https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/